# More efficient way than nested ifs

Tags: excel

In Excel, I want to use something other then nested if statements to execute a task. Is there a cleaner way of doing cases besides nested if statements? Is there a cases statement in excel? For example given a ordered tuple with ones and zeros (e.g (1,1,0)), I want the value of a cell to be something. Can I specify the ordered tuples in advance without something besides nested if statements?

Comment: You can usually make use of a table (could be hidden somewhere) and use a vlookup. And depending on what sort of data you have, you might even use `CHOOSE`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has worked for you that you would like to change? You can make use of 'lookup's, 'index', 'match', 'choose', 'AND', 'OR' and instead you can also spread your formula out over a couple clean columns instead of all in one cell.

Answer (score 4):

If you already know the ordered tuples and what you want the final value to be, why not create a reference table somewhere else on your sheet with `Col1` = tuple ; `Col2` = Wanted output?

Then just use a `Vlookup()` statement on that table...

Hope this makes sense / does what you want....